# Is there a pattern in JavaScript for loosely coupled objects.

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm relatively new to JavaScript so apologies if this type of question is an obvious one.

We have an app which uses etcd as its way to store data. What I'm trying to do is implement a way of swapping or alternating between different backend data stores (I'm wanting to use dynamodb).

I come from a C# background so if I was to implement this behaviour in an asp.net app I would use interfaces and dependancy injection.

The best solution I can think of is to have a factory which returns a data store object based upon some configuration setting. I know that TypeScript has interfaces but would prefer to stick to vanilla js if possible.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate _implement a way of swapping or alternating between different backend data stores_

Comment: Vanilla Javascript doesn't have any formal type specifications or interfaces. You can still do what you want, you just won't have any static type checking facilities. If you want that, you need TypeScript or something like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces are "merely" a static typing measure to implement polymorphism. Since Javascript doesn't have any static type system, it also doesn't have interfaces. But, it's a highly polymorphic language in itself. So what you want to do is trivial; simply don't write any interfaces as part of the process:

```
function StorageBackend1() { }
StorageBackend1.prototype.store = function (data) {
    // here be dragons
};

function StorageBackend2() { }
StorageBackend2.prototype.store = function (data) {
    // here be other dragons
};

function SomeModel(storage) {
    this.storage = storage;
    this.data = {};
}
SomeModel.prototype.saveData = function () {
    this.storage.store(this.data);
};

var m1 = new SomeModel(new StorageBackend1),
    m2 = new SomeModel(new StorageBackend2);

m1.saveData();
m2.saveData();
```

Using TypeScript and actual `interface`s gives you the sanity of a statically type checked language with fewer possible surprises at runtime, but you don't need it for polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I come from Delphi / C# etc.  And interface are just a pain in the but.
Javascript is so much nicer..

With javascript interfaces are not needed, just add the method.

eg.

```
function MyBackend1() {
   this.ver = 'myBackEnd1';
}

function MyBackend2() {
   this.ver = 'myBackEnd2';
   this.somefunc = function () { console.log('something'); }
}

function run(backend) {
   console.log(backend.ver);
   //below is like an interface supports
   if (backend.somefunc) backend.somefunc();
}

run(new MyBackend2());
//lets now use backend1
run(new MyBackend1());
```

Comment: Interfaces are extremely useful, if applied in the right circumstances. They're only a PITA if you overuse them dogmatically when they're not necessary.

Comment: @deceze:  It's a personal opinion, in real life application I've never found a need were interfaces would trump a simple javascript if (obj.method).  When I first came to javascript, I went the Typescript route, and in all honesty it frustrated rather than helped.  And the argument that if your app grows doesn't ring we me either.  I recently tried Typescript again, and again frustration ahoy, and lagging IDE.

Comment: Static type systems in general, which interfaces are a part of, are very powerful at avoiding certain types of errors *before runtime*. Yes, it's more work to use those type systems and they require a compilation process, but if applied correctly they can help development immensely. Sure, part of that is opinion-based, so I don't want to get into an argument. But dismissing static typing/interfaces out of hand **based on your opinion** is what I'm objecting to.

Comment: If I don't say what I think, then it's not my opinion, wherever you like it or not.